# How to mirror ios push notifications to windows 10 through Bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, apple-push-notifications, windows-10

I do not know of a single application that can do this. Clearly it should be technically possible because iphone's publish notifications to all kinds of device (fitbit, apple watch, etc.)

It this doable? Is the limitation on Apple's side or Microsoft's? Shouldn't following this [api](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html) lead me there

Comment: Yes, that is the right service. You need to implement BLE central on your Windows computer and connect to the ANCS service. You will also need an app on the iOS side to advertise a peripheral that your windows computer looks for, as from memory the ANCS service is not advertised unless there is another service advertising too.

Comment: In later versions of iOS, ANCS should be advertising all the time.

Comment: And this has never been done in an available application?